# How to update the location data in a single row in the server(without getting the data duplicated)?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Whenever I get a new location data it is getting saved in new row instead of the existing row getting updated with the new data. How can I achieve it? Below is my code:

```
ParseObject customerrequest = new ParseObject("CustomerRequest");
ParseGeoPoint parseGeoPoint = new ParseGeoPoint(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("parseGeoPoint");
customerrequest.put("location", parseGeoPoint);

customerrequest.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
       if (e == null) {
           Log.i("Parse Result", "Successful!");
       }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, you directly put the data using **.put** without removing the existing data using **.remove** w.r.t. the below line:

```
customerrequest.put("location", parseGeoPoint);
```

So, you should add this line `customerrequest.remove("location");` before this line `customerrequest.put("location", parseGeoPoint);` in the code. So, the code would look like:

```
    ParseObject customerrequest = new ParseObject("CustomerRequest");
    ParseGeoPoint parseGeoPoint = new ParseGeoPoint(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("parseGeoPoint");
    customerrequest.remove("location");
    customerrequest.put("location", parseGeoPoint);

    customerrequest.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
       Log.i("Parse Result", "Successful!");
    }
 }
 );
```

And on the server side, make sure you don't just use the **add** command to save the data. You should use **addOrUpdate** or **addOrReplace** or **saveOrUpdate** command depending upon the db you use.

Comment: please give me the command. I cant fine direct update command.

Comment: First do the changes in the above code as I've given and check if it works, brother. I've made changes in the code. Kindly check the above answer.

Comment: I tried the code.but it is not working. Unable to update in the same row.

Comment: What db you use on the server side? `mySql`?

Comment: Parse AWS ec2 server for saving data.

Comment: try this link:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_updating-inserting-using-staging-tables-.html